# Where to store calibration files for a custom Linux device driver

Tags: drivers, directory-structure

I've been writing a Linux device driver for some measurement devices I'm attaching to my Raspberry Pi.  I've [created](http://github.com/ams-tech/lkm) my kernel module and an application to access the character device driver, but the device needs to be calibrated regularly and I need to store the calibration data somewhere.  Where is that data usually stored?  My best guess is /etc, but I'd like to hear from someone who knows more about this than I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/), [`/var/lib/`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION) might be the right place:

> This hierarchy holds state information pertaining to an application or
>   the system. State information is data that programs modify while they
>   run, and that pertains to one specific host. Users must never need to
>   modify files in /var/lib to configure a package's operation.
>
> State information is generally used to preserve the condition of an
>   application (or a group of inter-related applications) between
>   invocations and between different instances of the same application.
>   State information should generally remain valid after a reboot, should
>   not be logging output, and should not be spooled data.

`/etc` isn't right for calibration data, since [/etc should be able to be mounted read-only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63037/4443).

Comment: Haha, well, I'm glad I asked!